# order by not formatted date sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, format

I'm storing Dates as string in the database with this format DD-MM-YYYY.

When I tried to make a select query with an orderby on the date column. I didn't get the expected result.

example of result : 
28/02/2013
27/02/2013
01/03/2013

My sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY strftime('%s', date_column)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you store dates as DD-MM-YYYY strings, which does not only prevent natural ordering of dates as strings, but also parsing them with [SQLite's date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Click the link and scroll down to 'Time Strings' section.

SQLite expects date/time strings in the natural order, most significant digit to least significant, that is, YYYY-MM-DD. You can use string operations to transform your DD-MM-YYYY strings into that form. For instance:

```
select 
  substr(reversed_date, 7,4) || '-' || 
  substr(reversed_date, 4, 2)|| '-' ||
  substr(reversed_date, 1, 2) as proper_date
  from (
    select '12-03-2000' as reversed_date
  )
;
```

You can either transform your date column into this format (as @peterm suggests) or just use the value of `proper_date` for sorting. You don't need to use `strftime` for that, but date-related functions will work with such values.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you need to change the format you store dates in from

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

to

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

From docs

> **Time Strings** 
>   A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>   YYYY-MM-DD
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
>   ...

Then your original query and this one will work as expected

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY date(date_column);
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY strftime('%s', date_column);
```

Output:

```
| date_column |
---------------
|  2013-02-27 |
|  2013-02-28 |
|  2013-03-01 |
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b343d/3)**

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) the following should work

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date_column)
```

Comment: This does not work. Try `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '12-03-2000');` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY to_date(date_column)
```

probably this might solve you problem as it is going for string comparison rather than date comparison so

01/03/2013 appears smaller than 28/02/2013 or 27/02/2013

thus output is :

01/03/2013, 27/02/2013, 28/02/2013

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: to_date

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me filter dates

```
SELECT inst.*,
       Substr(columnname, 4, 2)  AS newdate,
       Substr(columnname, 0, 3)  AS newday,
       Substr(columnname, 12, 5) AS newtime
FROM   table_name AS inst
WHERE  child_id = id
ORDER  BY newdate DESC, newday DESC, newtime DESC
```